# SSIS can't convert lob fields to varchar

Tags: hadoop, ssis, clob, lob

We've had some success with removing lob fields and avoiding row-by-row processing but with hadoop we can't seem to get around this.  In some cases, the fields in question are less than 10 characters yet ssis sees them as lobs.  is this an issue with hadoop, the odbc driver or ssis?  what steps can we take to make a determination? Help me Obi Wan Kenobi.  You're our last hope.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you can identify the columns that you need to convert add a data conversion step to those columns and then point those to the destination columns
and then set Validate External Data to False.

if this step also not working go into the advanced properties of the ODBC source and change the types back to something like DT_WSTR.

**The answer you will get!!!**